# Игра-головоломка. Алгоритм поиска соседних одноцветных квадратиков.

Tags: алгоритм

Доброго времени суток. Передо мной стоит задача написать игру-головоломку, в которой надо убирать группы кубиков одного цвета. Примерно, как [здесь](http://freeplayonlinegame.ru/ubrat-vse-kubiki_online-game_1229006481.html).
Собственно, возникли трудности с придумыванием алгоритма поиска соседствующих одноцветных кубиков. Прошу помощи в составлении алгоритма. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Поиск в ширину](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83).